# angular keyvalue pipe sort properties / iterate in order

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

When using the Angular [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe to iterate over an object's properties as follows:

```xml
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

I have experienced an issue where the properties were not iterated in the order expected. And this comment suggests that I am not the only one to experience this issue:

[How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819123/how-to-loop-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular/51735083?noredirect=1#comment92507958_51735083)

Can someone advise what determines the order of iteration when using the keyvalue pipe please and how to force a specific iteration order? My ideal order of iteration is the order in which the properties were added.

Thanks

Answer (score 329, accepted):

According to the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), the `keyvalue` pipe sorts the items by `key` order by default. You can provide a comparer function to change that order, and sort the items according to the `key`, to the `value`, or to the entry order of the properties in the object.

The following comparer functions sort the items in various orders:

```typescript
// Preserve original property order
originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
  return 0;
}

// Order by ascending property value
valueAscOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
  return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
}

// Order by descending property key
keyDescOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
  return a.key > b.key ? -1 : (b.key > a.key ? 1 : 0);
}
```

when applied to the `keyvalue` pipe:

```xml
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: originalOrder">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: valueAscOrder">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: keyDescOrder">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fq4tnb) for a demo.

---

Supplying a constant or `null` instead of a valid comparer function preserves the entry order of the object properties, like `originalOrder` does, but it causes an exception (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zeyvpp?file=src/app/app.component.html)):

```xml
<!-- The following syntaxes preserve the original property order -->
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: 0">
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: 374">
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: null">

<!-- but they cause an exception (visible in the console) -->
ERROR TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined
```

Moreover, using that syntax twice in the template does not display the items at all. Therefore, I would not recommend it. Please note that supplying `undefined` as the comparer function does not cause any exception but does not change the default behavior: the items are sorted by `key` value.

Comment: What if I don'y want them to be ordered at all?

Comment: @Tenzolinho - You can implement the comparer function as you like. You may try returning a random value to create an unordered list. Or maybe always returning zero.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you so much, you are a life saver. I wrote `keyvalue: 0` and they are in the original order.

Comment: `keyvalue: 0` no longer works in Angular 7. Just create a empty function: `sortNull() {}` and then set `keyvalue: sortNull`

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor#comment90891080_51491848

Comment: `keyvalue: 0` works in Angular 8.2.7. Thanks @Tenzolinho that's exactly what I was looking for, super clean.

Comment: @Mycah - Make sure that `keyvalue: 0` does not cause an exception. I updated my answer with a note about that syntax, and a suggestion for a valid `originalOrder` comparer function.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks, I went with `originalOrder() { return 0; }` based on a comment in in one of the other answers and no longer get the console error.

Comment: @Mycah - Please note that `originalOrder()` was based on [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order/52794221#comment97184742_52794221) to this answer.

Comment: The `originalOrder` function can be simplified to `originalOrder = () => 0`

Answer (score 32):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: 0">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>
```

directly write and you will get the data in sameorder as it is in the json

```
keyvalue: 0
```

Comment: I was please with that solution, then I opened the console and so a lot of error. 
ERROR TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined

Comment: create a function asIs() { return 0; }. The function can be added as: keyvalue: asIs

Comment: Also... You will need implement @PrasoonSrivastava suggestion... A "0" value don't works on build because type errors...

Answer (score 30):

Yes, by default the keyvalue pair sorting data in ascending order.

To keep it unsorted modify as:

```
keyvalue: 0
```

> Final code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue:0">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

> But for angular 7 or above, you need to put an empty function to keep
>   data  unsorted.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: unsorted">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

In your `.ts` file just put this empty function.

```
  unsorted() { }
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: It will work, but will also cause `core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined` ;). At least in Angular 10.

Comment: Worked for me with after adding attributes : 

   unsorted(a: KeyValue<number, string>, b: KeyValue<number, string>): number {
        return 0;
    }

Comment: ts:
`unsorted(a: any, b: any): number { return 0; }`  
html:
`<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: unsorted">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>`

Answer (score 21):

To keep the object order you can use

```
keepOrder = (a, b) => {
    return a;
}
```

Let's say you have

```
wbs = {
"z": 123,
"y": 456,
"x": 789,
"w": 0#*
}
```

If you use keyvalue you get alphabetical order by key

```
w 0#*
x 789
y 456
z 123
```

applying :keepOrder you keep object order

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let w of wbs | keyvalue: keepOrder">
    <ion-label>{{ w.key }}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{ w.value }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is same as accepted answer, but it has more complex object so It can help somebody How to sort by custom index field and using keyval pipe.

In angular component:

```
myObject = {
    "key1": { val:"whateverVal1", code:"whateverCode1", index: 1},
    "key2": { val:"whateverVal2", code:"whateverCode2", index: 0},
    "key3": { val:"whateverVal3", code:"whateverCode3", index: 2}
}
```

Sorting function in component:

```
indexOrderAsc = (akv: KeyValue<string, any>, bkv: KeyValue<string, any>): number => {
        const a = akv.value.index;
        const b = bkv.value.index;

        return a > b ? 1 : (b > a ? -1 : 0);
    };
```

in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of myObject | keyvalue:indexOrderAsc">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the parameter in sorting function be KeyValue<string,any>?

Comment: excellent solution "any" solved my problem I was using this inside datatable

Answer (score 8):

I prefer overriding default `keyvalue` behavior by extending it in my pipe. Then I use my pipe instead of `keyvalue` in my templates.

**For Angular >= 13**

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {KeyValuePipe} from '@angular/common';

const keepOrder = (a, b) => a;

// This pipe uses the angular keyvalue pipe. but doesn't change order.
@Pipe({
  name: 'defaultOrderKeyvalue'
})
export class DefaultOrderKeyvaluePipe extends KeyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    return super.transform(value, keepOrder);
  }

}
```

**For Angular < 13**

```js
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import {KeyValuePipe} from '@angular/common';

const keepOrder = (a, b) => a;

// This pipe uses the angular keyvalue pipe but doesn't change order.
@Pipe({
  name: 'defaultOrderKeyvalue'
})
export class DefaultOrderKeyvaluePipe extends KeyValuePipe {

  public transform(value, compareFn = keepOrder) {
    return super.transform(value, compareFn);
  }

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to override keyvalue this way, Type 'KeyValue<unknown, unknown>[]' is not assignable to type 'KeyValue<string, any>[]'.

Comment: @MahmoudEzzat see my post that will solve your problem ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try below piece of code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: 0">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but its leaving an exception in the console

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a cleaner solution. Uncomment the return statement that needs to give the right order:

```
interface KeyValue<K, V> {
  key: K,
  value: V
}

// Order by descending property key
  keyOrder = (aA: KeyValue<string,any>, bB: KeyValue<string,any>): number => {
    const a = aA.value.index;
    const b = bB.value.index;
    //return a > b ? 1 : (b > a ? -1 : 0); // ASCENDING
    return a > b ? -1 : (b > a ? 1 : 0); // DESCENDING
  }
```

**USE CASE**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y | keyvalue: keyOrder;">
   {{ x.key  }} indexes: {{ x.value.index }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Object` properties iterates randomly since it doesn't get stored as `array` in memory. However you can sort by properties.

If you want to iterate by insertion position, you need to create one extra property like `index` and set the `timestamp` and sort by `index`.

Below is the pipe you can use to control the sorting and iteration

Pipe

```typescript
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name: 'values'})
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): Object[] {
        let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(value),
            dataArr = [],
            keyName = args[0];

        keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
            value[key][keyName] = key;
            dataArr.push(value[key])
        });

        if(args[1]) {
            dataArr.sort((a: Object, b: Object): number => {
                return a[keyName] > b[keyName] ? 1 : -1;
            });
        }

        return dataArr;
    }
}
```

Usage

```xml
<div *ngFor='#item in object | values:"keyName":true'>...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a pipe to set default to unordered:

```js
// src/app/pipes/new-key-value.pipe.ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { KeyValuePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { KeyValueDiffers } from '@angular/core';
const unordered = (a,b)=>0

@Pipe({
  name: 'newkeyvalue'
})

// This pipe uses the angular keyvalue pipe. but defaults to unordered.
export class NewKeyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  
  constructor(public differs: KeyValueDiffers){};
  public transform (value, compareFn = unordered){
    let pipe =  new KeyValuePipe(this.differs);
    return pipe.transform(value, compareFn)
  }
}
```

links:

[Can I call an Angular2 pipe from a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633999/can-i-call-an-angular2-pipe-from-a-pipe)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.14/packages/common/src/pipes/keyvalue_pipe.ts#L25-L89

Template usage:

```
// src/app/some-component/some-component.html
<div *ngFor="let x of myObject | newkeyvalue>
</div>
```

register in the module.ts

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
import { NewKeyValuePipe } from '@/pipes/new-key-value.pipe.ts'
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    NewKeyValuePipe,
    ...
  ]
...
})
```

Comment: I'm unsure why but this code cause freezes in my app when keyvalue'ing form group values. When I extended `KeyValuePipe` instead of creating new instance in `transform()` it works fine.

Comment: How did you extend KeyValuePipe inside of the transform()?

Comment: He extended instead of not inside of

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 13.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: 0">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>

keyvalu: 0
```

is not working but empty unsorted method is working if you dont want to perform any sort of operations on existing array object.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue: unsorted">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

In your .ts file just put this empty function.

```
  unsorted() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement your own pipe (with correct typing) that takes a map as input and gives you back an array in the same order:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keepOrderKeyValue'
})
export class KeepOrderKeyValuePipe {

  transform<K, V>(input: ReadonlyMap<K, V>): Array<KeyValue<K, V>> {
    return Array.from(input, ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }))
  }
}
```

Or if you want to support multiple types like a **Record/Map** or handle **undefined**, you can implement it like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'keepOrderKeyValue'
})
export class KeepOrderKeyValuePipe {

  transform<K extends keyof any, V>(input: ReadonlyMap<K, V> | Record<K, V> | undefined): Array<KeyValue<K, V>> {
    if (input instanceof Map) {
      return Array.from(input, ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }))
    }

    return input
        ? Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => ({ key: key as K, value }))
        : []
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keepOrderKeyValue">
  {{item.key}} : {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular 17

The most suggested answer that DOESN'T WORK because types don't match:

```
keyvalue: 0
```

The shortest way:

```
originalOrder = () => 0;
```

In my case, this is the solution because of eslint rules:

```
public readonly originalOrder = (): number => 0;
```