# Angular: Is there a way to iterate over Map<,> without sorting?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I've got a `Map<string, customObject>` and I want to iterate over it using `*ngFor`.

I tried `*ngFor="let mapItems of map | keyvalue"` but this one sorts the keys in ascending order. I don't want the Map to be sorted at all. The values should be displayed in the original order.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular keyvalue pipe sort properties / iterate in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order)

Comment: Thank you very much! This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52794221/9888512 did it for me (originalOrder comparer)

Answer (score -1):

**You can write custom pipe.**

```
@Pipe({
  name: "appmap"
})
export class AppMap implements PipeTransform {
  transform(m: Map<string, object>): any[] {
    console.log([...m]);
    return [...m];
  }
}
```

**and can use like**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of map | appmap">
    {{item[0]}}:{{item[1] |json }}
  </div>
```

**Sample:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-ellis-hmw2p