# RxJS: using groupBy and creating key/value pairs from values

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have this array of observables:

```
animals$ = from([ 
   { animal: 'rat', color: 'grey', speed: 2 },
   { animal: 'rat', color: 'black', speed: 3 },
   { animal: 'dog', color: 'grey', speed: 2 },
   { animal: 'dog', color: 'black', speed: 1 },
   { animal: 'cat', color: 'grey', speed: 5 },
   { animal: 'cat', color: 'black', speed: 1 },
]);
```

I want to get an observable array of the following format, where the results have been grouped by animal type,  sorted alphabetically by animal, and the color values are transformed to keys for speed values:

```
[ 
   { animal: 'cat', grey: 5, black: 1 },
   { animal: 'dog', grey: 2, black: 1 },
   { animal: 'rat', grey: 1, black: 3 },
]
```

Is it possible by using groupBy? Most examples I have found so far are quite different, where in the results are in an array rather than combined to make key/value pairs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order does this awnser your question

Comment: In the input `cat - grey - speed` is 2. But in the output `cat - grey - speed` is 1. Is that a typo?

Comment: @MichaelD Yes my mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO better fit for this scenario would be the RxJS [`reduce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) operator + [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function to group the objects and RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator + [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to sort the elements of the array.

Try the following

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { map, reduce } = rxjs.operators;

const animals$ = from([ { animal: 'rat', color: 'grey', speed: 2 }, { animal: 'rat', color: 'black', speed: 3 }, { animal: 'dog', color: 'grey', speed: 2 }, { animal: 'dog', color: 'black', speed: 1 }, { animal: 'cat', color: 'grey', speed: 5 }, { animal: 'cat', color: 'black', speed: 1 }, ]);

animals$.pipe(
  reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const idx = acc.findIndex((item) => item.animal === curr.animal);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      acc[idx] = {
        ...acc[idx],
        [curr.color]: curr.speed,
      };
    } else {
      acc = [
        ...acc,
        {
          animal: curr.animal,
          [curr.color]: curr.speed,
        },
      ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []),
  map((animals) =>
    animals.sort((a1, a2) =>
      a1.animal > a2.animal ? 1 : a1.animal < a2.animal ? -1 : 0
    )
  )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djjn1t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes this solves it! Thanks a lot

Comment: the only thing I needed to add was `mergeMap((res) => res),` before reduce

Comment: @mponny: I don't actually see the need for `mergeMap((res) => res)` before `reduce` in the example you've provided. Indeed the Stackblitz example works without it. But if each element of the array is an observable, then you would need it.

Comment: I am quite new to observables, did not realize the difference between this example and my actual implementation (I was not able to post this due to customer confidentiality). Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score -1):

Another solution would be the following:

```
of([
  { animal: 'rat', color: 'grey', speed: 2 },
  { animal: 'rat', color: 'black', speed: 3 },
  { animal: 'dog', color: 'grey', speed: 2 },
  { animal: 'dog', color: 'black', speed: 1 },
  { animal: 'cat', color: 'grey', speed: 5 },
  { animal: 'cat', color: 'black', speed: 1 },
])
  .pipe(
    map((result) => {
      let res: { animal: string; grey: number; black: number }[] = [];

      const animals = new Set(result.map((x) => x.animal));

      animals.forEach((animal) => {
        const grey: number = result
          .filter((x) => x.animal === animal && x.color === 'grey')
          .map((x) => x.speed)
          .reduce((x, y) => x + y);

        const black = result
          .filter((x) => x.animal === animal && x.color === 'black')
          .map((x) => x.speed)
          .reduce((x, y) => x + y);

        res.push({
          animal,
          grey,
          black,
        });
      });

      return res;
    })
  )
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gwerwb?file=index.ts)

Comment: Yes, I am aware for both and I agree that the answer above is the best solution.

I only let this here because in the question, it doesn't have the requirement to be dynamic so I think that I introduce a more beginner friendly solution.