# Spreading a json object into an iterable

Tags: javascript, json, django, angular, typescript

In my Angular service script (following snippet) I receive a dictionary of customer data from my MongoDB database via Django:

```
getConsumersMongodb(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseMongodbApiUrl}`);
}
```

The dictionary that comes back is like this:

```
{
    "message": "Got all consumers' info successfully!",
    
    "consumers": {
        "id": 8, 
        "age": "51 - 60", 
        "gender": "Female"
        ...
    },
    
    "error": "Error!"
}
```

I am only interested in consumers data, so I parse it out in my Angular component TypeScript code like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dbService.getConsumersMongodb()
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.loadedConsumersDict = responseData;
        this.consumersInfo = this.loadedConsumersDict["consumers"]);
        console.log(this.consumersInfo);
      });
}
```

Of course, in my dev console, I get this:

```
{id: 8, age: '51 - 60', gender: 'Female', …}
```

So far, so good...

Now, I need to convert this json object into an iterable, such as an array, so that I can go through its fields and display them in my Angular html template.

So, I modified my code to this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dbService.getConsumersMongodb()
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.loadedConsumersDict = responseData;
        this.consumersInfo = this.loadedConsumersDict["consumers"]);
        let temp = this.loadedConsumersDict["consumers"];
        this.loadedConsumersArray = Object.keys(temp).map(function (key) {
          return { [key]: temp[key] };
        });
        console.log(this.loadedConsumersArray);
      });
}
```

But this gives me the following:

```
{id: 8}
{age: '51 - 60'}
{gender: 'Female'}
...
```

This is not what I want. How do I place the content into an iterable, so that I can simply use my following snippet in my html template code to display the fields?

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let consumer of loadedConsumersArray">
    <p><i>Id:</i> {{ consumer.id }}</p>
    <p><i>Gender:</i> {{ consumer.gender }}</p>
    <p><i>Age Group:</i> {{ consumer.age }}</p>
    ...
```

I have come a long way to achieve this much, but now I am confused and need help. I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**:

This is what I have written in my Django's `views.py` script:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def handle_consumer(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            consumers = ConsumerModel.objects.all()
            consumers_serializer = ConsumerModelSerializer(consumers, many=True)
            # Fetch consumer data from MongoDB.
            print(consumers_serializer.data)
            # end fetch region
            response = {
                'message': "Got all consumers' info successfully!",
                'consumers': consumers_serializer.data[0],
                'error': "Error in GET try"
            }
            return JsonResponse(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            error = {
                'message': "Fail! Cannot get all consumers!",
                'consumers': "[]",
                'error': "Error in GET except"
            }
            return JsonResponse(error, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

The `print` statement prints this:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 8), ('age', '51 - 60'), ('gender', 'Female'), ...])]
```

Because it always contains one item in this Python list, I do:

```
consumers_serializer.data[0]
```

to ensure that the response I get is this:

```
{'id': 8, 'age': '51 - 60', 'gender': 'Female', ...}
```

Comment: There is [no such thing as a JSON-'object'](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: If the JSON coming from the database is a dictionary you can't convert it to an array and it wouldn't make sense since there are no duplicate keys in a dictionary. Do you have multiple id's coming from the database? Are you sure your "dictionary" isn't actually an array of dictionaries in which case you don't need to do any more manipulations.

Comment: The data is already in the format you want... Why convert it to an array and use it in a ngFor?

Comment: You has not an array of object just an unique object. You can use [KeyValue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to "split" and show the properties and values, but I don't know if this is what are you looking for

Comment: Are you sure that `consumers` is an object and if so how does it carry multiple consumers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793944/angular-keyvalue-pipe-sort-properties-iterate-in-order

Comment: @Whitewolf3131 I have added an edit to answer your question about the list and dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`consumers` in the response is an object and not an array. Therefore, you don't need to convert anything into an array, and surely no need to use `*ngFor` if you don't have to.

Just make sure that `consumersInfo` is a public property, and then in your template write the following:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <p><i>Id:</i> {{ consumersInfo.id }}</p>
    <p><i>Gender:</i> {{ consumersInfo.gender }}</p>
    <p><i>Age Group:</i> {{ consumersInfo.age }}</p>
    ...
```